# GetAll method returns same values using hibernate and dataAccessUtil

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch data from a database using DataAccessUtil and Hibernate Session. The response to my getall function results in just one object values in the same number of elements.
Here is the piece of code that could help my point further.

getAll function:

```
public static <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> persistentClass) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> list = session.createQuery( "from " + persistentClass.getName() ).list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return list;
}
```

This is the call from my demo.java

```
List <Requirment> list=DataAccessUtil.getAll(Requirment.class);

    for (Requirment r:list)
    {

        System.out.println(r.getPid());
        System.out.println(r.getRid());
        System.out.println(r.getRname());
        System.out.println(r.getDesp());

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Please rephrase your statement and question.

Comment: Well Basically i need to fetch a list of objects from a database(requirement)

Once i run my demo.java instead of getting a list of objects i get one object being repeated again and again

for example if i have 3 objects in the table it returns the first object three times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your Requirment class look like? Ensure that it implements Serializable.

```
public class Requirment implements Serializable
```

What's the unique identifier on your object? Is it the pid? Make sure you have a unique column identifier in the database table and in your Requirment class.
Assuming pid is an identity column:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "pid", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getPid() {
   return this.pid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked with implements Serializable